# Send POST request in C# like a web page does?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simulate browser HTTP POST request and capture result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071321/how-to-simulate-browser-http-post-request-and-capture-result-in-c)

I have the following form in my web page...

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" id="username" name="username" size="30"/>
<input type="password" tabindex="2" id="password" name="password" size="30"/>
```

I use these to log into my website.
But I want to provide this functionality in my application as well.
How do I use a HTTP web request to send the user and password to my verification page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Hanselman has a great post about this:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx

(quite similar to @The Mask response, but a bit more verbose on the explanation)

Comment: This is the best answer because I understand the request now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8):

Try using the [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.
example:

```
var url = @"..."; 
var nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("username", "username");
nvc.Add("password", "password");
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var data = client.UploadValues(url, nvc);
var res = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine(res);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This looks more sane. I am going to try it.

Answer (score 1):

[How to simulate browser HTTP POST request and capture result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071321/how-to-simulate-browser-http-post-request-and-capture-result-in-c)