# How to fill a web form and submit it

Tags: c#, winforms, webrequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to simulate browser HTTP POST request and capture result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071321/how-to-simulate-browser-http-post-request-and-capture-result-in-c-sharp)
>   [Send POST request in C# like a web page does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377339/send-post-request-in-c-sharp-like-a-web-page-does)

I'm making a test application in c# and I was wondering how can I fill a webform.

There is just 1 box I want to fill ,Here the details are:

```
<td>Your name: </td>
      <td><input class="text" type="text" name="name" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
         <input class="text" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Login" />
```

So basically I would like to take the text of a textBox(its the easy part :)) inside of my WinForms application and put it into the **name** field which is on the url address and then send a request or press the **Login** button.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ([Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx))[WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx)

[How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)
[How to: Request Data Using the WebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx)

Comment: clarify that CodeBeast must know, whether remote script uses POST or GET (OP does not specify).

Comment: it's not clear.How can I declare the form name?!

Comment: Why would you want to declare the form name? It doesn't get send to the server??