# Forcing a page to POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cross-domain

This may be a very unusual question, but basically there's a page on another domain (that I can view, but can't edit/change) that has a button. When that button is clicked it generates some unique keys.

I need to pull those unique keys with my web service (using ASP .NET MVC3) I can get the initial HTML of the page, but how can I force the page to "click" the button so that I can get the values after the POST?

Normally, I'd reuse the code to generate keys myself, but I don't have access to the logic.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use e.g. firebug to see what POST parameters are sent with form and then make the same POST from your code.
For this you can use `WebRequest` or `WebClient`.
See this SO questions that will help you how to do it:

- [HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)
- [Send POST request in C# like a web page does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377339/send-post-request-in-c-sharp-like-a-web-page-does)
- [How to simulate browser HTTP POST request and capture result in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071321/how-to-simulate-browser-http-post-request-and-capture-result-in-c-sharp)

Then just parse the response with technology of your choice (I would use regular expressions - [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or LinqToXml if the response is well formed XML).

*Note: Keep in mind that your code will be dependent on some service you are not maintaining. So you can get in problems when the service is unavailable, discontinued or if the format of POSTed form or response will be changed.*

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the technology on the targeted site.

If the page is a simple HTML form then you can easily send a POST. You will need to send the expected data to the POST. Then you can parse the data.

If its not so straight forward you will need to look into ways to automate the click. Check Selenium. Also you might need to employ scrapping if the results page is a mess.