# How could I simulate request browser C#?

Tags: browser, request, simulation

I need to simulate a request to a page but I need to simulate it by code.
i'm using this code but not getting good results

`private string RemoteURLChecking(string url)`
`{try{`

```
   HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    request.Timeout = 8000;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (!response.ResponseUri.ToString().ToLower().Contains("pagenotfound"))
        return "The page exists";
    else
        return "Page not Found";
```

}
    `catch (Exception ex)`
    `{`

```
    return "Page not Found";
}
```

`}`

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simulate browser HTTP POST request and capture result in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071321/how-to-simulate-browser-http-post-request-and-capture-result-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few choices, each of which has plenty of examples on MSDN:

[Web Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.webclient.aspx)

[Web Browser Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)